# WSO2 : Can't build system service cdmf android agent

Tags: wso2

When i try to build system service application, i get this :

I use android studio 3.0.0

SDK API-24

Build tools 26.0.2

i use this documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Integrating+the+Android+System+Service+Application#IntegratingtheAndroidSystemServiceApplication-Operationssupportedviathesystemserviceapplication

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master      \system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\api\NetworkConnectedReceiver.java
Error:(64, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getCurrentUser()
Error:(65, 70) error: cannot find symbol method getCurrentUser()
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\api\OTAServerManager.java
Error:(21, 26) error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
Error:(36, 18) error: cannot find symbol class SystemProperties
Error:(278, 30) error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
Error:(162, 41) error: cannot find symbol variable SystemProperties
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\api\SettingsManager.java
Error:(33, 42) error: cannot find symbol method setDeviceOwner(ComponentName)
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\SystemService.java
Error:(35, 18) error: cannot find symbol class SystemProperties
Error:(426, 42) error: cannot find symbol method getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory()
Error:(718, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable SystemProperties
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\utils\AppUtils.java
Error:(20, 19) error: cannot find symbol class PackageInstallObserver
Error:(22, 26) error: cannot find symbol class IPackageDeleteObserver
Error:(57, 9) error: cannot find symbol class PackageInstallObserver
Error:(57, 47) error: cannot find symbol class PackageInstallObserver
Error:(214, 9) error: cannot find symbol class IPackageDeleteObserver
Error:(214, 47) error: cannot find symbol class IPackageDeleteObserver
C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\cdmf-agent-android-master\cdmf-agent-android-master\system-service\app\src\main\java\org\wso2\iot\system\service\utils\CommonUtils.java
Error:(53, 16) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 7s
Information:18 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Note that in my sdk, i can see class NonNull and SystemProperties.

Thanks for help.
Regards.

Comment: In order to build the system services app, you need access to developer restricted APIs. Have you replaced android.jar as mentioned in the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are not using correct target SDK and hidden APIs.

Please follow [Prerequisites section](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Customizing+the+Android+APK+File#CustomizingtheAndroidAPKFile-Prerequisites) in Customizing the android APK documentation to setup your android studio environment. Then you might be able to build system app.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't use not the correct SDK target.